# Polymorphic 'get' using hibernate, many to one, InheritanceType.JOINED

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, polymorphism

I have something like this..

A Car class that has one Seat from many seats. Seat has a sub class LeatherSeat.

```
public class Car {
  private Seat seat;
  ...
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  public Seat getSeat() {
    return seat;
  }
  ...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Seat {
  private String id;
  private String color;
} 

@Entity
public class LeatherSeat extends Seat {
    private String leatherType;
}
```

When I create my Car and make my Car's seat a LeatherSeat it saves all correctly on the db.  When I want to then get my Car (using a Criteria or Query list) and I read getSeat() the Seat is always just a Seat, never a LeatherSeat.  I cannot cast (exception) and seemingly must manually get the LeatherSeat by id.

Is this a limitation of using the JOINED inheritance type or am I missing something.  How do I get Seat as a LeatherSeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if you do a lazy fetch, like you are doing with getSeat, you will only ever get the parent, never the sub-class.   I tried this same example with FetchType.EAGER and getSeat correctly returns a LeatherSeat.

I am unsure why hibernate can get a Car with a LeatherSeat when for EAGER fetch but hibernate cannot seem to get it when do a LAZY fetch.  Seems like something is broken there.

There is a ticket regarding discriminator columns on an InheritanceType.JOINED where a point is made regarding this scenario.  https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/ANN-140 but the ticket was rejected indicating that hibernate was too elegant for needing a discriminator for InheritanceType.JOINED.  Yet it fails to correctly return sub-classes on lazy fetches.

Then this ticket https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-271?focusedCommentId=44089#comment-44089 is more specific to this issue and the answer there was 'how are we suppose to know what sub-class to get on a lazy fetch?'

Both tickets are old and were rejected.  Seems like a problem to me.  But for now you would have to change to a different inheritance type or use eager fetch type as this is according to design by hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

In the LAZY case, the seat will be a "proxy", which is instantiated when the Car is instantiated. At that time, Hibernate does not know whether the seat will be leather or not.

When you traverse the property, and it is lazily loaded, then Hibernate will know that the Seat is leather, but it cannot retrospectively change the class of the proxy. However, all the data is there. The seat will respond as a LeatherSeat if you have overridden any methods.

If you really need to cast this object to LeatherSeat, you can unbox the proxy using http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/engine/PersistenceContext.html#unproxy(java.lang.Object)

See this blog for more on why the proxy will always be Seat, not LeatherSeat: http://sessionfactory.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/hacking-lazy-loaded-inheritance.html

This is covered briefly in the Hibernate docs here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-proxies